# Best practice discussion: When to favor a webview over a native UI in titanium?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, cross-platform, titanium

I'm currently working on a cross-platform mobile app and have gone through the process of creating the UI of my application using the given Titanium api.

Compared to when you are building a mobile web application this is a time consuming task, because you don't have the possibility to work on the rendered UI like you can on a rendered webpage using firebug.

Especially form creation is bothersome, so I decided to build my forms using html and render them in a Webview, which worked out pretty sweet for several reasons:

- WebViews are automatically scrollable, so the soft keyboard won't cover the input fields in your HTML form
- You can control which keyboard type is displayed with a WebView form by setting attributes on the `<input>` tag.
- You can use JavaScript libraries to add form validation, field highlighting, and so forth to an HTML form.

Although this works like a charm and the titanium documentation encourages you to use webviews for building forms, I have mixed feelings about having mixed native UIs with webviews.

My questions to you:

- What do you think of mixing native UIs with Webviews?
- Do you have other use cases that favor a Webview?
- What could be general criteria for using one or the other?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where does the Titanium documentation encourages the use of Webviews ?

Comment: https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/WebView+Use+Cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What do you think of mixing native UIs with Webviews?**

The real question would be : Do you care about the user experience ? If yes, then go exclusively Titanium/Native. Sometimes, you need to use the Webviews to get around some problems (I had one year ago) : I remember I couldn't open online PDF files with Titanium : As Android platforms didn't open the PDF "natively" ([Now you can](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/72361/open-pdf-file-on-android)), you had to pass the pdf's path to a Webview. That was the only time I was forced to pop up a WebView.

**Do you have other use cases that favor a Webview?**

If you are you talking about frameworks that base the rendering on Webviews then : 
If you have a client who owns a full static website and tell you to turn it into a mobile application It could be useful. Or, If you aim many platforms (more than Titanium does), you can use frameworks such as PhoneGap that will allow you creating WP7/iPhone/Android/BlackBerry apps.

**What could be general criteria for using one or the other?**

Which platform are you aiming ? As I said, Titanium won't allow you exporting your app for the WP7 platform.
Then, if you need better performances, then go for Titanium/Native apps. 
On the other hand, if you want to reuse your code, think PhoneGap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Currently I'm aiming for IPhone and android.
Actually I was thinking about using phonegap in the first place, but after experiencing performance issues with rendering lists I switched to titanium. Do you think that was a mistake?
Do you think the webview performance will improve in the future?

Comment: No, it's not the mistake ... it's exactly what I did. I switched from PhoneGap to Titanium because the WebView rendering is a little bit slower that the native one and there a a number of out-of-the-box useful functionalities (YQL, Facebook API, ...). Then, with PhoneGap, to create a basic app, you need HTML, CSS and JavaScript. With Titanium, one language : JavaScript.As I said, if you will not use your HTML/CSS/JS elsewhere, then go for Titanium.

Comment: Thanks that helped removing the insecurity and I think I will stick to what I have done so far.