# How do start with complex level cross-platform mobile application development?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, cross-platform, mobile-application

Is there any document to develop cross-platform mobile application. I have try to go with phonegap but I couldn't find any documentation to develop high level application using that like, server communtication, with social networking integration, Game development etc.

I have already gone through the basics for that and also have gone through its site [Phonegap.](http://phonegap.com/)

If anybody is having such documentation please do share.

I have also searched that there are other cross-platforms supports like, titanium appcelerator etc. But not having any knowledge about that.

I would be really thankful as i want to learn cross-platform mobile application development.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do?  Is javascript the best option for what you want to do?  There are limitations in corss-platform applications, decide if you can live within those limits first.

Comment: @James Black: I have already knowledge about iOS native development. Now i want to develop cross-platform applications like games and all. So I guess such cross-platform APIs (Phonegap, Titanium, Corona, etc.) would be easier for me rather than to learn Windows as well Android. So please suggest me which to choose and where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, before jumping in the cross platform development mobile world, you have to choose between :

- HTML/JS/CSS based method that will allow you to embed your web application in an executable using a framework(Like Phonegap).
- A framework that will allow you to program using one language (For example, in Titanium, you use Javascript) and then turn is into a full native iOS/Android application.

Then next question that will come to your mind is : Which one should I use ? Well, we already discussed [it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5548517/html5-web-app-vs-native-mobile-apps/5548935#5548935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8869100/best-practice-discussion-when-to-favor-a-webview-over-a-native-ui-in-titanium/8869342#8869342). To sum up that post, Titanium (obviously) renders the views quicker. Use Phonegap if you have an existing website and want to use the same client logic (using the same js, html and css).

The last question is about documentation : For Phonegap, I think that the documentation is clear and you have to use your own web developer skills.
On the other hand, for Titanium, personally I didn't buy a book : I find the documentation easy to read. What you have to do is practicing and then, you will face some bugs or lacks in the Titanium framework. 
If you want, you can find a couple of books in Amazon ([like this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513961)).

EDIT :

AFAIK, Windows Phone is not in the Appcelerator's roadmap. I know that the community wishes this platform instead of BlackBerry (always in beta?).

For your question, personnally I prefer Titanium because it really what users want : a true user friendly experience through an adequate UI. Imagine, with one code, you can get two dedicated UI without styling. In Phonegap, I had to create a CSS for iOS and another one for Android.

It's all about UI. Because the business layer is the same. 
I really recommand you to try both frameworks (or more) and create a true app with a tables, animations, notifications, web service call, geolocation, transitions and a social sharing functionnality. Then, you can have a true idea about each framework.

EDIT 2 :

To get started with Titanium, you can have a look at some tutorials [at this web page](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Home).
But, what it really helped me to improve is:

- The very [complete documentation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest)
- The KitchenSink project [hosted here](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink). It can help to see how to put in place a good project architecture, shows some good practices, etc.

But beware, Titanium is really good for business apps but limited for games.

Comment: Corona could be used. Apps seem to be developed in Lua. More info here: http://developer.anscamobile.com/resources/apis

Comment: @Zakaria: So do you mean Titanium is the better option than Phonegap? I know the native development for iOS but not having knowledge about Android & WindowsMobile development. So I want to go with cross-platform mobile development (FYI).
Please feel free to post your suggestions

Comment: @Zakaria: So according you Titanium is preferable. Really thankful to you for helping. Can you please provide any online link for Titanium learning documentation, whichever you use?

Comment: @mrunal : See the EDIT2.

Comment: Titanium is expensive

Answer (score 0):

Corona would be a good choice for Game development. Titanium is good choice if you want native apps. Phonegap is a good choice if you want/have HTML content but need to access native features like contact lists or camera.

If you go down the route of building an HTML5 app, I would strongly recommend some type of background syncing of content. It is a much better user experience to load html pages from the phone's local disk versus from the web, as discussed in this article - http://www.thorntech.com/2013/01/html5-vs-native-apps-which-will-win-the-mobile-app-development-battle/